# Getting 404 error after uploaded the data on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I  am using  codeigniter. I did the project and uploaded on server but when I am running my URL getting 404 not found. I had changed the `base_url` path but still getting issue. On local server its working. I have created on folder on server name is test and inside test there is admin folder, inside admin all codeigniter code available.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://test.hybreed.co/admin/'; 

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';// also remove the index.php 

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$route['default_controller'] = 'home';// i have created home in controller
```

The database is ok. Where am I wrong?

Comment: First add an index.html. Your code is on risk via http://test.hybreed.co/

Comment: You means file name should be first latter in capital and class name  first name should be in small latter

Comment: Check whether url rewrite is on or not.

Comment: where i have to add the index file.

Comment: Ankii where i have to check the rewrite option

Comment: index file is  added.and where i have to check   the rewrite option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `home.php` under controllers folder to `Home.php` and inside that file rename `class home` to `class Home` and then check.

**Controllers**

Controller class names should be all lowercase, except the first letter.

```
If your URL is www.example.com/gallery, the controller name is Gallery.
If your URL is www.example.com/admin_folder, the controller name is Admin_folder.
```

Controller file names should match the class name, but be all lowercase.

```
Gallery :: gallery.php
Admin_folder :: admin_folder.php
```

Controller methods should be all lowercase as well. There is some flexibility with uppercase, but similar to URLs, there are opportunities where it can goof something up.

Comment: Thanks for reply but now my class name is Home and my file name is home.php but think is that  i am getting error 404 not found

Comment: Try rename file to `Home.php` and then check.

Comment: Now my issue resolved. Just Rename the file name ....Thanks for your help Ankii  Gangrade....

Answer (score 0):

Please put `phpinfo()` in any php file under web directory and check for "Loaded Modules" in browser.if you can see `mod_rewrite` then it is enabled and otherwise not.you have to also check for `mod_reques` modules. and make sure that you have put .htaccess file at proper place.

Comment: Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/hybreed/public_html/test/admin/application/controllers/Home.php:77)

Comment: Please go through your /home3/hybreed/public_html/test/admin/application/controllers/Home.php if you have used redirect or header function then make sure before that function you have autoload session library.

Comment: make sure it is before any redirect or header function call or ny echo statement used.This error occurs when you send any data to browsers before session will write its cookie.can you put index part of your home controller.